# Eclipse Hono - 404 Error while creating a Tenant

Tags: eclipse-hono, eclipse-iot

I am using the command as shown in the below documentation to create a Tenant in Hono.

https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/api/management/#/tenants/createTenantWithId

```
curl -X POST "http://srvgal89.deri.ie:28080/v1/tenants/DEFAULT_TENANT_11" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"

<html><body><h1>Resource not found</h1></body></html>
```

As per the documentation : All operations, except the tenants resource are required. The tenant management might be outside of the scope of the device registry and managed by a higher level system. In this case all calls should simply return 404.

I am assuming this might be the reason for getting Resource not found. But I am not sure what do you mean by outside the scope of device registry.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need to omit the *accept* header.

Comment: I am still getting the Resource not found error after omiting the access header.